# xdmp:email and AWS SES

Tags: marklogic, amazon-ses, marklogic-9

I'm trying to use AWS SES to send email from MarkLogic using the 'xdmp:email' command, but I keep getting an "address not verified" error.  I have tried supplying verified email addresses in every conceivable email field (reply-to, sender, from, etc) but I have not found a way around this particular error using simply xdmp:email. It is worth noting that if I enter an unverified email address into the "sender" field, for example, both unverified email addresses will appear in the error message.  This tells me 1) I have entered the reply-to, sender, etc addresses correctly in xdmp:email and 2) AWS is noting those addresses and, if verified, letting it go through.  The problem is this email address I really don't have control over.  The error is:

```
Error sending mail: : 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. 
The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1: daemon@ip-10-62-92-128.ec2.internal
```

I am entering the credentials in the options.  All-in-all, I am fairly confident that everything else is correctly done.  For example, until I entered credentials I received an authorization error.  Until I validated the actual TO addresses, I received errors that those addresses were not properly validated.  I've been able to resolve those errors.  The bulk of this email code is in full operation outside of AWS so I'm not overly worried there is some basic problem with the code.

FWIW, we have requested a "paid" SES account and therefore we are no longer working in a "sandbox."  We have deleted and recreated the SMTP IAM User. Googling suggests that upgrading should have sufficiently addressed this problem, with the User issue as second idea, so I'm frankly unclear if this is an AWS issue too. Regardless of those AWS-specific questions, it seems to me that I should be able to send an email from MarkLogic relatively easily via the SES sandbox, versus having to immediately upgrade to a paid account.

Is there something I am missing?  I would very much like to be missing something simple.  Is there some way not to have ML attach this dummy email address to the message?  Is there a way to validate this dummy email address in such a way that it is scalable should the service expand?  Is the common solution to verify the domain, which, for me, will not be a simple matter?  Should I be looking at setting up a localhost SMTP relay using postfix or something (and, of course, who knows if that will actually get around this issue)?  How are others using MarkLogic and SES together in AWS?

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when either the FROM or SENDER email headers are not validated.
Authentication is first step but doesnt bypass the from/sender checks.
First verify in some other tool that SES is configured correctly for the same email address.  You may need to try using a smtp relay or some similar low level tool to debug this. 
The settings for xdmp:email include a "from" but not a "sender"  (often called 'Envelope From') -- BOTH these need to be validated SES email addreses.

A workaround is to configure a local smtp proxy using something like postfix can be configured to work with SES correctly and has the benefits of good smtp spool processing for handling retries/errors and intermittent load issues that are beyond the xdmp:email abilities.

Comment: Just to be clear, the FROM and SENDER email addresses are validated.  I can readily get another application (not MarkLogic) to work correctly with these addresses within AWS using SES.  It is also possible to include these headers in the xdmp:email message itself, via the rfc822 namespace. The issue appears to be that MarkLogic is attaching what appears to be an unverifiable email address - daemon@ip-10-62-92-128.ec2.internal - to every message.